# Per-thread singleton-like using thread_local storage

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, thread-local, thread-local-storage

Is there any caveats of this usage of `thread_local` storage duration:

```
template <class T>
inline T &thread_local_get()
{
  thread_local T t;
  return t;
}
```

Then in different threads (for example)

```
thread_local_get<float>() += 1.f;
```

The doc at cppreference says this about thread local storage duration:

> thread storage duration. The object is allocated when the thread begins and deallocated when the thread ends. Each thread has its own instance of the object. Only objects declared thread_local have this storage duration. thread_local can appear together with static or extern to adjust linkage.

Does this correctly allocate one `thread_local` instance for each T (during compilation) and each calling thread ? Is there any situation that can lead to e.g undefined behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see theoretical caveats, as after the instantiation(s) the template should behave (from the point of view of the compiler) exactly like a normal function.

Still, I would recommend checking your compiler support for `thread_local` before using it: for example gcc had [a bug with class static `thread_local` members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722941/thread-local-member-variable-construction) which seems to be still present at least in the latest TDM-GCC distribution featuring gcc 5.1.0. I don't know if this particular bug also affects static members of functions (it should not) and probably you are using a different compiler, but still my suggestion is to make some experiments before using this feature.

Comment: I accept this as the solution as it seems from a "standard" point of view that this is correct code, I even found an iso proposal implementation using the same exact code (for what it worth). But you do have a point when reminding that compilers are not 100% bug-free.. :)